# Output array in (elem,elem,elem) format?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to output an array like so:

```
(elem,elem,elem)
```

For example, if the array is `[2, 3, 4]`, it would print:

```
(2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
puts "(#{array.join ','})"
```

This is a pretty simple solution that uses Ruby's [string interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#Ruby) and [`Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join). I can give a more detailed explanation if you need it.

Of course, you can use `print` or anything, really; the string that contains the result you want is just this:

```
"(#{array.join ','})"
```

Note that you *must* use double-quotes (`"`) for the external pair. The internal pair can be either single or double and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [ 2, 3, 4 ]
result = '(%s)' % [ arr.join(',') ]
```

Comment: @QPaysTaxes `#join` concatenates the array elements into a string using the given separator. The `%` operator uses the left-hand string as a format string, replacing the format sequences with the elements in the right-side array.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by joining the array. See the below code

```
array = [2, 3, 4]
value = "(#{arr.join(',')})"
value = p "(#{arr.join(',')})"  # if you want to assign the result into variable after print it in console
```

Comment: I'd like to note that you should just use `"(#{arr.join(',')})"` if you don't want it to be outputted as well; if you do, then what you have is good.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yes you are right. This is answer is for th e people who would like to print and store the result